# Angular How to fill text inputs based on a remote Typeahead selected option

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter, typeahead

I have created aninvocing form based on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/) but I changed the Description input by a Typeahead that works with remote url to bring the data from the database of all the products that I have. What I need to know is how after I select the product in the Typeahead, I can update the cost input field with the cost of the product.

The typeahead url is JSON that I generate in the codeigniter controller and it works perfectly. That JSIB brings the Product name and cost.

This is a sample of the table when I select the cost keeps showing 0. Even that I set the value of the input automatically when the Typeahead selection.

```
  <input ng-model="item.cost" type="number"  ng-click="item.cost = null" class="form-control" value="selectedProduct.cost" ng-required ng-validate="number" size="6"  />
```

When I check the element it shows that the cost input value is filled by {{selectProduct.cost}} (e.g value="599") but it is still showing 0:

[image]

Typeahead angular code

```
 $scope.selectedProduct = null;

  // instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
  var numbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.collection); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: "products/getproducts",
             wildcard: '%QUERY'

        }
  });

  // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
  numbers.initialize();

  $scope.numbersDataset = {
    displayKey: 'collection',
    source: numbers.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      empty: [
        '',
        'No products were found...',
        ''
      ].join('\n'),
    }
  };


  // Typeahead options object
  $scope.exampleOptions = {
    displayKey: 'collection',


  };
```